# If Promises Repeatedly Awaited Never Resolve, Does It Cause a Memory Leak?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, memory-leaks

If repeatedly awaited (or .then()ed) promises never resolve, will all the promises and execution contexts eventually be garbage collected or will it cause a memory leak?

e.g.

```js
async function whatHappens() {
  await neverResolves();
  doSomething();
}

function neverResolves() {
  return new Promise(() => {});
}

function doSomething() {
  console.log('never happening');
}


// main thread
for (/* very long loop */) {
  whatHappens();
}
```

I understand even a hung promise will be garbage collected if there are no references to it, but I'm not sure if awaiting it will count as a "reference" thus preventing the whole garbage collection process and leaving in memory paused functions. Or whether it will still happen and the paused functions will also be garbage collected.

A knowledgeable human response would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you write code that deliberately doesn't resolve a promise, then is it a memory leak as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if awaiting it will count as a "reference"

No. On the contrary, `await` does not create a reference *to* the promise from the paused function but rather *from* the promise to the paused function - the resumption of the function is registered as a promise handler (i.e. `.then()` call).

So if the promise is never settled and there are no more references to it (including resolver functions that *could* settle it), both the promise and the paused function will get garbge-collected.

Comment: This directionality is the perfect explanation, and I haven't seen it out there. Thank you.